# How to invoke the Server Manager to cache results?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows

In Windows 2008 R2 Server, it usually takes very long until the **Server Manager** shows the items under the **Roles** node on two of our servers. However, once that has been done the first time after a reboot, it seems to be a lot faster.

How can I mimic this behavior without having to manually start it the first time around and clicking any relevant node, so that the first time I actually go in and use the server manager it will be a lot faster to use it?

In case that isn't easy to answer or the symptoms point to odd behavior (I never knew it differently on these versions), I'd like to ask for ways to debug the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because it refreshes the list from scratch on a reboot, and caches it for that session. I've noticed it as well and take it for what its worth, which is a minor annoyance.

Comment: I don't consider waiting three minutes a minor annoyance when it comes to *quickly* logging on to do a minor task that in itself takes 15 seconds. I realize that it caches it, my question actually implies that, btw. I want to find out how to mimic it or debug the slowness to get rid of it.

Comment: On my heavy 2008 R2 boxes, its anywhere from 10-30 seconds. How many roles and features do you have installed?

Comment: Five out of seventeen: AD Domain Services, DNS Server, Network Policy and Access Services, Web Server, Windows Server Update Services.

Comment: What do your server resources look like?

Comment: 2 GiB of RAM on a Xeon 5110.

Comment: wow 3 minutes is nuts but since its a DC after a reboot there is a lot going on.

Comment: also most task can be done without the server manager, I just drop into powershell to accomplish most of these tasks.

Comment: As an example, the server that I mentioned, is a 64bit 2008R2 Enterprise machine, w/ 72GB of memory and it takes 10 seconds to load Roles and Features. I know this doesn't answer the question, but I wanted to throw it out there.